# How to define a interval over the Real numbers in Solve domain?

Tags: equation-solving, intervals

When we use the `Solve[]` function, we can especify a domain. This domain can be `Reals, Integers...`. But how can I define a domain to be a interval over the real line. For example I want to solve the equation $\cos x=\sin x$ what I only want the answers between $0$ and $\pi/2$ for example.
I've try the following:

`Solve[Sin[x]==Cos[x],x,Element[x, Interval[{0,\[Pi]/2}]]`

but this raise the error that is not a valid domain. How can I do what I want? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider just adding it as a constraint in the system, e.g.: `Solve[{Sin[x] == Cos[x], 0 < x < Pi/2}, x]`.

Comment: @eyorble thats a way of doing it, I don't know why I didn't think of it before. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Solve[{Sin[x] == Cos[x], Element[x, Interval[{0, π/2}]]}, x]
```

> `{{x -> {-2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]}}}`

```
SolveValues[{Sin[x] == Cos[x], Element[x, Interval[{0, π/2}]]}, x]
```

> `{{-2 ArcTan[1 - Sqrt[2]]}}`